# Advanced Excel: Sum of relative cells of a category

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I’m a designer. I have a list of tasks, with hours, and I’ve split them into milestones. I want to count the number of hours for each milestone.

Here’s a picture:

[image: Excel of design time sheet]

*In other words:* I want to look at the value in the M column, if it’s 1, I want to get the cell across it, then repeat down the rows, and sum the whole lot.

See if you can figure that one out with the least cell wastage! :) (This is Numbers for Mac, so no macros or vbscript or what-have-you.)

Comment: Is PivotTable available? http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/pivottable-reports-101-HA001034632.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Excel the **SUMIF** formula can be used.

Assumption: In picture above, the 'Hours' label is in cell A1
The formula for 'Milestone 1' in cell E2 would be:

```
=SUMIF($C2:$C11,RIGHT(E1,1),$A2:$A11)
```

The syntax of the formula is:

```
=SUMIF(range, criteria, sum range)
```

The criteria is determined by using the last character in the 'Milestone' heading.